# Unable to view image from s3 but image is visable in postman

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3

I have a api the returns a image file. It works fine in postman and swagger, I am able to view the image.

Here is that api

```
[HttpGet("GetImage")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetImagesAsync()
{
    Stream imageStream = await _fileOperation.ReadObjectData("computer.png");

    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", new ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = "computer.png",
        Inline = true // false = prompt the user for downloading; true = browser to try to show the file inline
    }.ToString());


   return File(imageStream, "image/png");
}
```

Here is my code to get image in typescript

```
  getFileImage() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'FileExplorer/GetImage');
  }

this.fileExplorer.getFileImage().subscribe(file => {
  this.any = file;
}, error => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

When I call it in angular I get this error
error = SyntaxError: Unexpected token '�', "�PNG

I want to display the image in home.component.html

Comment: I'm not familiar much with the C# APIs but do you think you are missing the content type header? for example `Content-Type: image/png`? because from the error it looks like the browser is trying to interpret the response as text instead of a bin image.

Comment: Thank you for your help @AzeemHassni but then why would it work in postman and with swagger also I belive that I worte the type in  return File(imageStream, "image/png");